# Python, change email to name format

Tags: python, pandas

How can I parse the below email options to just expected output. These are not in a dataframe, they are separate strings. I have a loop that loops through each string.

example input

```
Louis.Stevens@hotmail.com
Louis.a.Stevens@hotmail.com
Louis.Stevens@stackoverflow.com
Louis.Stevens2@hotmail.com  
Mike.Williams2@hotmail.com
Lebron.A.James@hotmail.com
```

expected output:

```
Louis Stevens
Louis Stevens
Louis Stevens
Louis Stevens
Mike Williams
Lebron James
```

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have pandas objects, you probably shouldn't be using the `pandas` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `s` the input Series, and using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import re

s.str.replace(r'^([a-z]+)\.(?:.\.)?([a-z]+).*', r'\1 \2', regex=True, flags=re.I)
```

Output:

```
0    Louis Stevens
1    Louis Stevens
2    Louis Stevens
3    Louis Stevens
4    Mike Williams
5     Lebron James
dtype: object
```

For individual strings:

```
import re

s = 'Louis.a.Stevens2@hotmail.com'

out = re.sub(r'^([a-z]+)\.(?:.\.)?([a-z]+).*', r'\1 \2', s, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: @mozawy Exactly. Good job! Votated

Answer (score 3):

Remove everything after `@` with regex `@.*`:

```
s = pd.Series("""Louis.Stevens@hotmail.com
Louis.a.Stevens@hotmail.com
Louis.Stevens@stackoverflow.com
Louis.Stevens2@hotmail.com""".splitlines())

s.str.replace('@.*', '', regex=True)
#0      Louis.Stevens
#1    Louis.a.Stevens
#2      Louis.Stevens
#3     Louis.Stevens2
#dtype: object
```

Comment: what if my string is like  `email = Louis.Stevens@hotmail.com` ? and its not in a series?

Answer (score 3):

Use regex's `findall` to extract the alpha numerics at the start of sentence and  the alphanumeric immediately before `@` . Then proceed and replace digits with nothing. Code below

```
    email
0        Louis.Stevens@hotmail.com
1      Louis.a.Stevens@hotmail.com
2  Louis.Stevens@stackoverflow.com
3       Louis.Stevens2@hotmail.com
4       Mike.Williams2@hotmail.com
5       Lebron.A.James@hotmail.com






  df= df.assign(email_new =df['email'].str.findall('^\w+|\w+(?=\@)').str.join(' ').str.replace('\d','', regex=True))

              

                           email      email_new
0        Louis.Stevens@hotmail.com  Louis Stevens
1      Louis.a.Stevens@hotmail.com  Louis Stevens
2  Louis.Stevens@stackoverflow.com  Louis Stevens
3       Louis.Stevens2@hotmail.com  Louis Stevens
4       Mike.Williams2@hotmail.com  Mike Williams
5       Lebron.A.James@hotmail.com   Lebron James
```

Comment: sorry i should have expanded, there will be more then the one louis stevens.

Comment: What do you mean? How are they written?Let me know, sure it can be done

Comment: I mean - there may be a louis stevens in one string, and tom stevens in another string, or mike williams in another. I have a loop that loops through the emails of many people.

Comment: Not clear, please give a sample input and  df expected result?

Comment: Does that help or you need more assistance?

Comment: it helps, however is there a way to just do it to one string? I have a loop that goes through a list of names... ie  newemail = email.{regex}